# How do I add an Applicative context to a type expected by Lens' MyDataType?

Tags: haskell, types, applicative, haskell-lens

I have a function generalized over a function `func` to be applied on `MyDataType1` and another `MyDataType1` like this

```
setThis :: (Functor f0, Applicative f0) => Lens' MyDataType1 (f0 Float) -> Float -> MyDataType1 -> MyDataType1 -> MyDataType1         
setThis func toThis dataType1 dataType2 = dataType2 & func %~ (\a -> (+) <$> a <*> delta
    where baseStat = dataType1 ^. func -- baseStat has type Maybe Float
          delta = (\a -> toThis * a) <$> baseStat -- also have type Maybe Float
```

where `MyDataType1` is (when used with `print`. Every numeric value is a `Float`)

```
data MyDataType1 = MyDataType1 { _name = Just "First"
                               , _length = Just 5.5 
                               , _dmsTypes = Just
                                     ( DMS { _i = Just 1.9
                                           , _j = Nothing
                                           , _k = Just 95.9
                                           }
                                      )
                               }
```

The function `setThis` given a default record function like `length`, a constant `Float`, **a data set to get base value from** and **a data set to modify**, sets `_length` to a number that's a sum of the original value and the value from the other set multiplied by some constant.

It works just as I expect when given function `length`.

What I want to do is have the exact same behavior when given a function like `(dmsTypes . _j)` as in

```
setThis (dmsTypes . _Just . _j) 0.3 (someY) (someY) -- someY :: MyDataType1
```

Although GHC throws this error if I do just that

```
Could not deduce (Applicative f) arising from a use of ‘_Just’
  from the context: Functor f
    bound by a type expected by the context:
               Lens' MyDataType1 (Maybe Float)
Possible fix:
    add (Applicative f) to the context of
      a type expected by the context:
        Lens' MyDataType1 (Maybe Float)
```

And while it seems like GHC knows exactly what I should do, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: `setThis` expects a lens, i.e., that you can always set or get exactly one value. However, the optic `dmsTypes . _Just . _j` is not a lens, because there is nothing to set or get if the `_dmsTypes` field is `Nothing`. What would you like to do with this `Nothing`?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia Oh! That makes a lot of sense. If `_dmsTypes` is `Nothing` I would want it propagated. So if `setThis` encounters `Nothing` in the set I get the data from, it should do nothing. The function should only 'set' something in the `dataType2` if `_dmsTypes` is `Just x`.

Comment: Hm, does my answer do what you want if `_j` is `Nothing` in `dataType1` but `Just _` in `dataType2`, or the other way around? Or does it not matter?

Comment: It does. Since I'm using applicative operators, the behaviour is similar to fmap on `Just` but simple addition on `Nothing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the thing `func` points at might not exist, it should be a *traversal* (any number of focused values) rather than a *lens* (exactly one focused value).

The part of `setThis` that uses a *setter* (i.e., `(%~)`) remains the same, but the *getter* part (i.e., `(^.)`) should instead use a *fold*, with `(^?)`. In that case, `dataType1 ^? func` will have two layers of `Maybe`, one from `(^?)` and one from `func` (in what is currently `f0`), that you'll probably want to flatten with `join`.

```
baseState = join (dataType1 ^? func)
```

Now `f0` must be `Maybe`.

```
setThis :: Traversal' MyDataType1 (Maybe Float) -> ...
```